# CBPeripheral track written record

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

From database, I am retrieving data records and then writing each record to `CBCharacteristic` of BLE device. Write implementation,

```
for service in self.connectedPeripheral!.services! {

   for characteristic in service.characteristics! {

       if characteristic.UUID.UUIDString == "1111" {

         self.connectedPeripheral!.writeValue(dataRecord, forCharacteristic: characteristic, type: .WithResponse)

       }
   }
}
```

Now `CBPeripheral`'s `didWriteValueForCharacteristic` method is getting called with `nil` `NSError`. So write is successful. But how can we track which data record is written to BLE device. Because I need to delete this successfully written record from database. In `CBCharacteristic` documentation, I could not find any property which can be set to database `record_id` when we start write operation to BLE. Most of them are read only.

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {

   print("write characteristic: \(characteristic)")
   // Need to track the record here So it can be removed from database

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting response in **peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error** method, you have to call this method **[peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic]**

By this you will get callback in **peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:**
here you can check your characteristic's value and delete the record if its successfully written to your characteristic.

```
-(void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {

  if (error == nil) {
   NSString *characteristicValue=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSLog(@"value=%@",characteristicValue);
  }
}
```